# Can a single Node<E> direct to LinkedList?

Tags: list, tree

I'm currently working on building a general tree with pre-order structure. However, since my tree can have multiple children, I need to make a list that contains nodes and make that inner node directing to the next list.
I'm wondering if I can build that kind of structure on Java
If I can. Can I direct a single node to the DoublyLinkedList structure in code?

Here is my Node class in the Tree class (code fraction)

```
class Tree<E> {
    //single node structure
    private static class Node <E> {
        private E e;
        private Node<E> parentNode;
        private LinkedNode<E> childList;

        public Node(E e, Node<E> p, LinkedNode<E> n) {
            this.e = e;
            this.parentNode = p;
            this.childList = n;
        }
    }

    //list structure to store nodes
    private static class  LinkedNode<E> { //<- problem1
        private Node<E> parentNode;
        private Node<E> nextSibling;
    }
    private E root;
    private int size = 0;
}
```

The problem with my code is at LinkedNode part I have to make the object type as Node not just E otherwise it will not contain a node info. So, is there any way to make this done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class Tree<E> {
    //root of the tree
    private Node root;
    //single node structure
    private static class Node <E> {
        //Store data of the node
        private E e;
        //store the child in an ArrayList
        //Each child will be represented by Class Node itself
        private ArrayList< Node<E> > childList;
    }
    private int size = 0;
}
```

What I perceive, is you're trying to implement a generic tree. Here's how I would've done it.
Cheers!

Comment: Oh, so it would be better using ArrayList instead of LinkedList. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, and also the idea is to store the entire child node in ArrayList/Vector. (including its data and its child nodes)

Comment: yeah, I see that but would it be possible to enter(with iteration) into the arraylist and find what specific child node is pointing to?

Comment: Yes, you could loop through each child node using an iterator. Now to process a child node's children, we can use recursion as we normally do in case of Binary Trees.